# ReferenceError: data is not defined in angular 6

Tags: angular6, ngoninit

I'm calling a service from one of my component, via the `assignGirdle` function. While this service is being executed, I get the above error, but when I check in the network tab and click on the API call, in response in can see the data.

**Note `girdleNew` is of type `any`. Also this function I'm calling on `ngOnInit()`.**

```
assignGirdle() {
  this.diamondSearchService.getDistinctValues()
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.girdleNew = data;
  }, error => {
    this.alertify.error(error);
  });
}
```

The service:

```
  getDistinctValues() {
   return this.authHttp
   .get(this.baseUrl +  'distinct/girdle')
   .map(response => response.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have imported service in your component. Below is my data service import.

```
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
```

Create object of the same in your component:

```
constructor(public data: DataService) { }
```

In my component I have called this `getUser()` method which is defined in `DataService`.

```
this.data.getUser(email).subscribe( data => { 
    if(data.length > 0){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Below is my service:

```
getUser(email){
    // definition
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution